# How to persist variable in Azure Durable Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I created an Azure `Durable functions` that seems is working fine but then I have a while loop that is causing me a head ache.

This is my durable function:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
                [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
            {
                var output = string.Empty;

                bool resumed = false;

                var powerBIAuth = await context.CallActivityAsync<AzureAuthentication>("PowerBIAuthenticate", "");
                    // here generate the report
                    var response = await context.CallActivityAsync<ResponseRequestReport>("GenerateReport", powerBIAuth.access_token);
                    if(response != null)
                    {
                        response.token = powerBIAuth.access_token;

                        while (true)
                        {

//***PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE*****//
//***The second time it tries after the sleep, the response variable that I pass to the function is null.. why? *****//

                            response = await context.CallActivityAsync<ResponseRequestReport>("ReportStatus", response);

                            if(response.percentComplete == 100)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            // Orchestration sleeps until this time.
                            var nextCheck = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddSeconds(20);
                            await context.CreateTimer(nextCheck, CancellationToken.None);
                        }

                    }

                return output;
            }
```

If you see the code the first thing happens is to wait until I get a token, then I call other function to generate a report and then I do a while in order to wait that the report completion is done.

The first time I it checks the Status the `response` variable has a value, the second time it tries after the sleep the `response` variable that I pass to the `ReportStatus` function is **`null`**, and because is null all the code in that function crashes.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Seems that after a sleep the orchestrator lost the persistant of the local variables. This is breaking my head.

Any clue?

Comment: One thing you should understand is that DF does not persist local variables. It only persists the data sent to/from activities etc. So it can replay your code, read the results from the history table and assign variables as if the activity had been a method call. That said, the code does look like it would work though.. Could you check that you are actually returning data on the first ReportStatus activity call?