# Azure Functions: Orchestrator and Activity best practice

Tags: azure-functions

Good day,

My question is mostly about best practices for using the Activity and Orchestrator functions.
Haven't found the answer here - [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp)

**In short** - I have a simple orchestrator that:

- retrieves some list of objects from an API (using Activity)
- processes these items (filters and sorts) (directly in Orchestrator)
- sends processed items to another API (using Activity)

**Question**: both API calls in Orchestrator (await context.CallActivityAsync()) is asynchronous and takes some time to execute. Functions framework unloads orchestrator (I'm on consumption plan) from memory and replays from the beginning (which is expected).
Every replay orchestrator gets saved (if executed already) state on vars from context.CallActivityAsync() calls, BUT not from local vars (e.g. objectsStartWithA, objectsStartWithB and `filteredObjects` from example below). It doesn't break anything but does the same things on every replay (if any) over and over again.
Do I need to extract all business logic to Activities and call them using await context.CallActivityAsync()?

```
namespace Demo.Functions
{
    public class FunctionClass
    {
        public const string FunctionName = "Function1";

        private readonly ILogger<FunctionClass> _logger;

        public FunctionClass(
            ILogger<FunctionClass> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [FunctionName(FunctionName)]
        public async Task ExecuteAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(_logger);
            logger.LogInformation("Process started");

            var someObjects =
               (await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<ApiObject>>("GetApiObjectsAsync", null)).ToList();

            var objectsStartWithA =
                someObjects
                        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) && x.Name.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ToList();

            var objectsStartWithB =
                someObjects
                        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) && x.Name.StartsWith("b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ToList();

            var objectsToCompare = objectsStartWithA.Union(objectsStartWithB);


            //Long-running api request
            var someOtherObjects =
               (await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<ApiObject>>("GetOtherApiObjectsAsync", null)).ToList();

            var filteredObjects =
                someOtherObjects
                        .Where(x => objectsToCompare.All(z => z.Id != z.Id))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                        .ToList();


            //Saving
            await context.CallActivityAsync("SaveObjects", filteredObjects);

            logger.LogInformation("Process finished");
        }
    }

    public class ApiObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: apparently "DF does not persist local variables. It only persists the data sent to/from activities etc" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442256/how-to-persist-variable-in-azure-durable-functions

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My understanding is that ALL variables will be re-evaluated (on every replay), however variables that is using context.CallActivityAsync() calls will check internal table (durable framework internal history table) if this variable has a value already (so the actual Activity function will not be called twice if value already in history table). My question is about variables objectsStartWithA, objectsStartWithB, objectsToCompare and filteredObjects.
Do I need to wrap them also in Activity function or leave in Orchestrator? What is the best practice here?
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would push those into an Activity and keep the orchestrator purely just coordinating the various activities. In the example you've given, I'd just change `GetApiObjectsAsync` activity to return the data in the filtered form you want, rather than introduce another activity call tbh. IMHO, that would just incur additional/unnecessary steps in the orchestration workflow & state storage that you don't need.

Maybe your example is simplified, but looks like you only care about `objectsToCompare` - which is objects starting with 'a' or 'b'. So, a single filter applied in your existing activity function before returning, would do the job.

Comment: You're correct - I just took a simple example :)
Usually we tend to keep logic separated by layers - data access, business logic.
I mean, in real life GetApiObjectsAsync should retrieve raw data (without filtering, etc), as it might be used in different places.
After, to filter and other sorts of manipulations I should have another activity function for that (even if it incur additional steps in orchestration workflow & stage storage...)
But to summarize I got the idea.. orchestration function MUST NOT contain business logic inside but just context.CallActivityAsync() calls